# Calculate Running Total using subgroups

Tags: tableau-api

I have a workbook in Tableau that shows sales by team. The team group is broken up into buckets based on how many years of experience the team member has. I want to calculate  a sort of running total for these buckets, where the total for the "1+" column will include everything below it.

```
                     Total in bucket           Running total
TeamName       1+    3                         10
               2+    2                         7
               3+    5                         5
```

Any ideas on how to do this? I assume I have to do something like Table Calculation > Running Total > Running along = *advanced*

Answer (score 0):

A few table calculations are sensitive to the order that you traverse the addressing (aka compute using) fields, such as running totals and difference from previous value.

You can either specify to "compute using" bucket and sort your buckets in descending order. Or you can use the advanced tab to partition by TeamName, address by bucket, and specify the order for the buckets on the bottom of the advanced dialog box.

Specifying the sort in the advanced dialog has the advantage of allowing you to display the buckets in whatever order you liked without affecting the calculation. Leaving the order unspecified has the advantage of allowing to change the sort on the worksheet and have the calculation adjust to your new sort automatically. The right choice depends upon which behavior you want.